# Codeigniter : public, membre, admin

Tags: php, codeigniter, admin, extends

In this file I have something like that :

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_CONTROLLER
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }   
}

class MY_Membre_Controller extends MY_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }   
}

class MY_Admin_Controller extends MY_Membre_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Then in my controllers/ I have for exemple

```
class Member extends MY_Membre_Controller
{ 
    /* .. construc etc */

    public function loadPicture() ...

   others functions ..
}
```

Now what Can I do to have an `Admin` class extending `MY_Admin_Controller` and can use the Member method ( because an admin is an Member with others functions )
Because I can't manage to use the Member method doing something like that :

```
class Admin extends MY_Admin_Controller
{
    /* construct */

   /* function index() 
      { 
          $this->loadPicture
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're making your own controller extensions for these in the first place. Why not make your Member controller an interface instead of a class, then have your Admin_Controller implement that interface? You'll have access to the methods, and the is-a relationship will still hold that an Admin_controller is-a Member_controller, and your Admin controller will also have access to the methods defined in Member_Controller by virtue of the fact that they are actually implemented in Admin_Controller. Additional classes that implement Member_controller while implementing the methods contained, also giving them an is-a relationship to Member_controller.

I'm butchering your code here, just trying to get the idea across, so you'll want to clean it up:

```
interface MY_Member_ControllerI extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct();
    public function loadPicture();
}

class MY_Admin_Controller implements MY_Member_ControllerI{
    public function __construct(){
        //some contruct stuff
    }

    public function loadPicture(){
        //load the picture
    }

    public function adminMethod(){
        //some admin stuff
    }
}
class My_Member_Controller implements MY_Member_ControllerI{
    public function __construct(){
        //some contruct stuff
    }

    public function loadPicture(){
        //load the picture
    }

    public function memberMethod(){
        //some admin stuff
    }
}
```

So at this point,  both Admin and Member have an is-a relationship to the MY_Member_ControllerI interface, making them both the same root type

Or, overload the methods in your Admin_Controller so that when a child class  calls them, the appropriate method in the parent class of Admin_controller, Member_Controller, is invoked.

For example

```
class MY_Member_Controller extends MY_Controller{
    public function __contruct(){
        //construct stuff
    }
    public function doStuff($stuff){
        //do some stuff with stuff
    }
    public function loadImage(){
        //implement load image
    }
}

class MY_Admin_Controller extends MY_Member_Controller{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        //plus other admin stuff
    }

    public function adminOnly(){
        //admin only stuff
    }

    public function loadImage(){
        parent::loadImage();
    }
}

class Admin extends MY_Admin_Controller{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        //plus other admin stuff
    }

    public function adminOnly(){
        //admin only stuff
    }

    public function loadImage(){
        parent::loadImage();
    }
}
```

I'm thinking of some other ways you could do this too. Is there any way you can rethink your reusable architecture though? It sounds like you could really benefit from some other methods of inheritance like interfaces and abstract classes, or abuse method overloading.

Comment: This is a nice solution, but where will you place them ? In which file/directory ?

Comment: I've honestly never hacked around with CI's CI_Controller class like this before, so I honestly don't know. Normally with interfaces I would just keep them in their own package, and then any implementers would just use that package to get the interface, but that's putting a Java perspective on a PHP problem, but the same ideas apply.  As a proof of concept you could put everybody in the same pool to make sure it does what you want it to, then there are several ways you could structure it. All up to you really.

Comment: @Choubidou CI doesn't auto load unknown files, so you'll have to put everything you want to extend from in 1 file under core/MY_Controller i.e: defining multiple classes inside that file, one of them should be MY_Controller